# How to run and debug React Native Android App in VSC?

Tags: android, react-native, visual-studio-code

I currently need to use the following steps to run and debug React Native Android App using Android Studio and Google Chrome:

1. Start up Android Studio
2. Setup emulator
3. Go to terminal, run **npm start**
4. Choose the desire flavour
5. Run the emulator
6. Remote debug in Chrome

I wonder if life can be made easier to use Visual Studio Code (possibly with some official plugin) to do all the above in a single click? Please list out the steps to configure it.

Comment: There is a plugin already as of today (March 2022) that lets you debug with breakpoints on VScode. Not sure how to get that to work though.

Answer (score 2):

Debug react native android and ios app using Visual code, We need to add addition plugin into VSC **React native-Full Pack**

**Step 1.**

Install React Native - Full Pack extension

**Step 2.**

Connect the mobile device using USB debugging mode or open emulator from the android studio.

Step 3.

Click on debugging option from the left menu in visual code studio Click on Add configuration and select React Native then create launch.json

**Step 4.**

Open dev option in the phone on the long back press or shake the phone and Enable Debug js remotely

**Step 5.**

Final step click on play button and select Debug android or Debug ios

For more information refer this link

https://medium.com/@tunvirrahmantusher/android-debug-with-vscode-for-react-native-96f54d73462a

Comment: Thanks, but I guess I have seen that page before. Like in step 2, it still requires Android Studio. I am after a full VSC solution (with some plugins or command lines at most). And I would prefer the official React Native Tools rather than this React Native Full Pack.

Comment: There is no need of android studio you can connect real device rather than emulator. React native full pack is a vsc plugin.

Comment: No I am using emulator (see my original question)

Comment: Then where are you stuck??

Comment: Your answer involves Android Studio to start the emulator. My question is about full VSC solution that uses emulator (i.e. VSC also start/stop the emulator). Because of that, I can't accept yours as the answer.

Comment: I am not want to say accept my answer i just want to solve your problem

Comment: Suggesting me not to use emulator does not solve my problem unfortunately.